# Limit SQL statement to year

Tags: sql

I want to take the two following statement and get only the results for 2013.

```
SELECT
  COUNT(DISTINCT
    CAST(c1.caseseqnumber AS VARCHAR) + '-' + CAST(c1.year AS VARCHAR)),
  COUNT(DISTINCT
    CAST(c2.caseseqnumber AS VARCHAR) + '-' + CAST(c2.year AS VARCHAR))
FROM 
  caseparticipants c1 LEFT JOIN caseparticipants c2
  ON c1.year=c2.year AND c1.caseseqnumber=c2.caseseqnumber
     AND c2.participanttype = 'Appellant Rep 1'
```

and second one

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  c1.caseseqnumber, 
  c1.year 
FROM 
  caseparticipants c1 LEFT JOIN caseparticipants c2
  ON c1.year=c2.year AND c1.caseseqnumber=c2.caseseqnumber
     AND c2.participanttype = 'Appellant Rep 1'
WHERE
  c2.year IS NULL
Order by year ASC, Caseseqnumber ASC
```

Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried?  I see a "WHERE c2.year IS NULL", so this can't be that hard.

Comment: When i try that it removes all the correct results. if i do c2.year = '2013' i do not get the result set i need

Comment: Right, but we have no idea what result set you get, and what you're looking for.  Not sure how anyone could possibly help.

Comment: the result set i am getting is all the cases that dont have a rep, but i need to limit down all of the results that i am getting to a certain year.  the statement works to get the proper result set for all years, but i want to limit it to a certain year

Comment: @parkjohnston Some more detail about your tables here would help, since we all seem to be pretty confused about what you're looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If looks like you already have a `year` field, so just add that to your `WHERE` clause:

1:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT CAST(c1.caseseqnumber AS VARCHAR) + '-' + CAST(c1.year AS VARCHAR)), COUNT(DISTINCT CAST(c2.caseseqnumber AS VARCHAR) + '-' + CAST(c2.year AS VARCHAR)) 
FROM caseparticipants c1 
LEFT JOIN caseparticipants c2 
  ON c1.year=c2.year AND c1.caseseqnumber=c2.caseseqnumber 
    AND c2.participanttype = 'Appellant Rep 1'
WHERE c1.year = 2013
```

2:

```
SELECT DISTINCT c1.caseseqnumber, c1.year 
FROM caseparticipants c1 
LEFT JOIN caseparticipants c2 
  ON c1.year=c2.year AND c1.caseseqnumber=c2.caseseqnumber 
    AND c2.participanttype = 'Appellant Rep 1' 
WHERE c1.year = 2013
  AND c2.year IS NULL
ORDER BY year ASC, Caseseqnumber ASC
```

Comment: the is null is getting me the results that are not in the table..which is getting me the correct results.

Comment: So do you need records where `c1.year` is 2013, but there's no match in `c2`?

Comment: Just add it to your `WHERE` clause. I've edited my answer above.

Comment: that returns all results for that year

Comment: ?? Isn't that what you want? You're going to have to be clearer about what you're looking for. Please post some sample data or something.

Comment: resloved..thanks. I was connected to the dev box, thus some results were missing compared to what the client wanted